# How can I unfold a bash function that has inner functions in it?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, functions

Suppose I source the function `myfunction` defined by

```sh
myfunction(){
    myinnerfunction 
}
```

where `myinnerfunction` is defined as

```sh
myinnerfunction(){
    echo word
}
```

I'd like to find an equivalent of `declare -f myfunction` that displays the content of the inner function `myinnerfunction`, i. e.

```sh
myfunction ()
{
    echo word
}
```

instead of

```sh
myfunction ()
{
    myinnerfunction
}
```

Now, what if I have inner aliases instead of inner functions?

Comment: If this question was on stackoverflow it would be a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426077/how-to-define-a-function-inside-another-function-in-bash

Comment: My question is "how to unfold the function with inner functions in it?"

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to define your use of the term "unfold" and express how it's different from the question I linked? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking. You'll just have to run `declare -f` for the inner function. To explain, Bash treats functions just like any other command; e.g. you could `unset -f myinnerfunction` then put a script `myinnerfunction` in your PATH and it would work exactly the same.

Comment: I concur with @wjandrea. To achieve that feat, Bash may only bind command names to function references at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short script that searches for inner function and define them at the same time (1 depth level only)

```
function declare-recursively () {
    declare -f $@
    declare -f | grep ' () {' | sed 's/ () {//' | while read i
    do
        declare -f $@ | grep -Po "[\t, ]$i " | while read j
        do
            declare -f $j
        done
    done
}
```